# Why Xcode simulator view is different from view-hierarchy view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I am developing a `UIImageView` on top of `UICollectionView` using autolayout constraints:

I have anchored the `UIImageView` to take the top part of screen with a fixed H:W ratio of 4:3, then let `UICollectionView` to take whatever space is left at the bottom.

Strangely, when I ran it, the view in xcode simulator is quite different from the view-hierarchy debugger:

**View Hierarchy Debugger**:
[image: View Hierarchy Debugger]

**iPhone 8 Plus simulator**:
[image: iPhone 8 Plus simulator]

In the `UICollectionView`, each cell will show a face photo, I have configured the itemSize of `UICollectionView` to be a square. It should show then entire face (so the debugger view is correct, the simulator is not).

```
// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    // set item size 
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {



        // gw: to force one row, height need to be smaller than flow height
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.height, height: collectionView.bounds.height)
    }
}
```

***What could be the cause of this difference***?
I am using xcode 10.1, ios 12.1
Full code is here (not very long):

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UICollectionViewController{

    let collectionViewCellIdentifier = "MyCollectionViewCellIdentifier"
    let canvas:Canvas = {
        let canvas = Canvas()
        canvas.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        canvas.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
        canvas.alpha = 0.2
        return canvas
    } ()

    let photoView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()

        imageView.image = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "hongjinbao")
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        return imageView
    } ()


     private let myArray: NSArray = ["First","Second","Third"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        // stack views
        view.addSubview(photoView)
        view.addSubview(canvas)

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        collectionView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        collectionView?.register(PersonCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: collectionViewCellIdentifier)


        setupLayout()


    }

    private func setupLayout() {


        photoView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        photoView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor,   multiplier: 1.333).isActive = true
        photoView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        photoView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        canvas.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: photoView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        canvas.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: photoView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        canvas.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: photoView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        canvas.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: photoView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        collectionView?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: photoView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView?.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: photoView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView?.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: photoView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true


    }

}


// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource
extension ViewController {

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: self.collectionViewCellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 13
    }


}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    // set item size 
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {



        // gw: to force one row, height need to be smaller than flow height
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.height, height: collectionView.bounds.height)
    }
}



    import UIKit

    class PersonCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

        let face: UIImageView = {
            let imageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.image = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "mary")
            imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return imageView
        } ()

        let name: UILabel = {
            let textLabel = UILabel()
            textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return textLabel
        } ()

        let desc: UITextView = {
           let textView = UITextView()
            textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return textView
        } ()

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)

            setupView()
        }


        // gw: needed by compiler
        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }

        private func setupView() {
            addSubview(face)
            addSubview(name)
            addSubview(desc)

            backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-16-[v0]|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0":face]))
        }




    }
```

Comment: First of all, make sure you use the same screen size on the interface builder and on the simulator. second, you added constraints on runtime, so clearly you expect some difference. I would check also for constraints error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause, it is due to the stacking order of subviews in my `ViewController`.  The `photoView` was add on top of the `collectionView`, and it blocked part of `collectionView`.

Solution: in `viewDidLoad` add below statement to bring the later one to front:

```
 // stack views
        view.addSubview(photoView)

        // little trick to bring inherent collectionView to front
        view.bringSubviewToFront(self.collectionView)
```